# Changed value not being sent to a Blazor component's parent

Tags: blazor

> **Note** To make it clearr what I'm doing, I added a [sample project to github](https://github.com/MrYossu/TestFormRowComponents). This shows the use of the `FormRowText` component, which works fine, and the `FormRowDropdownEnum` component, which doesn't work. If anyone is able to download this project and see what I've done wrong, it would be great.

I am trying to write a series of reusable Blazor components for laying out form controls. Most of these are working (eg for an `<input>`), but one is giving me problems. The idea is to pass an `enum`'s type as a parameter, and the component will create a `<select>` based on the `enum` values.

I made a generic component as follows (.razor first)...

```
@typeparam T

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="@PropertyName" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">@(Caption ?? PropertyName)</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10 input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="far fa-@Icon"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" name="@PropertyName" id="@PropertyName" @onchange="@OnChanged">
      @foreach (T v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()) {
        if ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), v.ToString()) == Value) {
          <option value="@Convert.ToInt32(v)" selected>@Enum.GetName(typeof(T), v)</option>
        } else {
          <option value="@Convert.ToInt32(v)">@Enum.GetName(typeof(T), v)</option>
        }
      }
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code behind looks like this...

```
  public partial class FormRowDropdownEnum<T> where T : Enum, IConvertible {
    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    private async Task OnChanged(ChangeEventArgs cea) {
      int val = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), cea.Value?.ToString() ?? "0");
      await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(val);
    }
  }
```

It is used as follows (assuming that `_customer` is a model that has a `Frequency` parameter which is of type `Frequency` (an `enum`)...

```
<FormRowDropdownEnum PropertyName="@nameof(Customer.Frequency)"
      T="Frequency" @bind-Value="(int)_customer.Frequency" Icon="wave-sine" />
```

This displays the `<select>` correctly, and sets the appropriate `<option>` depending on the model's `Frequency` parameter.

When the selection is changed in the `<select>`, the `OnChanged` method is called, and the correct value is used as the parameter for the event call back. However, the Blazor page that holds this component (ie the one that has the `<FormRowDropdownEnum>` tag shown above) never sees the new value, and the model there is not updated. I put a breakpoint on the model's setter, and it was never hit.

As I said, I have similar components for other input types, and they work fine, so I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.

Anyone able to help? Thanks

**UPDATE** Following the reply by enet, I tried adding a private variable in the code behind and modifying that when the input value changed...

```
    private int _value;
    protected override void OnParametersSet() =>
      _value = Value;

    private async Task OnChanged(ChangeEventArgs cea) {
      int val = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), cea.Value?.ToString() ?? "0");
      _value = val;
      await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(val);
    }
```

I changed the Razor markup to use `_value` instead of `Value` as follows...

```
if ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), v.ToString()) == _value) {
```

However, the result of this was that when I changed the selection in the dropdown, it was immediately reverted to the previous value, and the parent page never saw the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [your repo working](https://github.com/BrianLParker/FormRowDropdownEnum)

`FormRowDropdownEnum.razor`

```
@typeparam TEnum

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="@PropertyName" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">@(Caption ?? PropertyName)</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10 input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="far fa-@Icon"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" name="@PropertyName" id="@PropertyName" @bind="Value">
        @foreach (var enumValue in EnumValues)
        {
            @ChildContent(enumValue)
        }
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

`FormRowDropdownEnum.razor.cs`

```
public partial class FormRowDropdownEnum<TEnum>
{
    private TEnum _value;
    [Parameter] public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Caption { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Icon { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public TEnum Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value.Equals(value)) return;
            _value = value;
            if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
            {
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
            }
        }
    }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TEnum> ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TEnum> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<TEnum> EnumValues => Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Value is not Enum) throw new ArgumentException("Value must be of type Enum");
    }
}
```

`Index.razor`

```
...
      <FormRowDropdownEnum PropertyName="@nameof(Customer.Frequency)" @bind-Value="_customer.Frequency" Icon="wave-sine" Context="freq">
          <option value="@freq">@freq</option>
      </FormRowDropdownEnum>
...
@code {

  readonly Customer _customer = new Customer {
    Name = "Jim",
    Email = "jim@spriggs.org",
    Frequency = Frequency.Monthly
  };

  private string _msg = "";

  private void OnSubmit() =>
    _msg = $"Customer name: {_customer.Name}, email: {_customer.Email}, frequency: {_customer.Frequency}";

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I couldn't get this to work. I got a compiler error "The child context element 'ChildContent' of component'InputEnum' uses the same parameter name ('context') as enclosing child content element 'ChildContent' of component 'EditForm'. Specify the parameter name like: '<ChildContent Context="another_name"> to resolve the ambiguity". Sorry if I'm being dumb, but I'm fairly new to Blazor, and not sure what this means.

Comment: Also, I'm confused by your usage. If you look at my original question, you'll see the sort of usage I have with the other components. I want this one to work the same way. Thanks again

Comment: If your using it inside another context you need to name one of them.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Please could you take a look at the sample project I linked at the top of my question, and see what I need to do to get this to work. At the moment, you can change the dropdown, but the new value doesn't seem to make it up to the parent, so the parent page model isn't updated. Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You could render the selects options in the child component, this allows the user to edit the option template.

Comment: Thanks for the updated project. I see it works, but I don't understand your code. Where in Index.razor do you tell the component the enum type? In my code, I had the `T` parameter, but you've removed that. Also, your code returns the enum value as a string, eg `OneOff`, whereas mine returned it as an `int`. An `int` is much easier to work with, as you can easily cast it to the enum, and the database stores the value as an `int` anyway. If the parent page gets a string, it has to do work to convert that to an enum value. Is there any way around this? Thanks again.#

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You don't have to it works it out from reflection from the type of Value. Why do you need to tell it the type when your passing the instance is a better question....

Comment: It does not return it as a string your just seeing the display which is a string. If it was a string you would not be able to assign it to the property this is C# not Java.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you've done. That's really clever. I did have the vague feeling that as I was passing in an enum value, I ought to be able to get the enum itself without having to pass that in separately, but I was so busy with trying to get it to work that I forgot about the idea. Thanks for the tip, makes much more sense now.

Comment: Actually, one other question. What is the `AdditionalAttributes` property there for? You don't seem to use it anywhere

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Additional attributes allows attribute splatting ... Making your component a lot more flexible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters

Comment: Thanks for that link, very interesting reading. I love the name ""splatting"!